# Any chance to disable the lazy loading using ListView on Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I've this code:

```
ListView(
   children: episodes.map((Episode episode) {
     return EpisodeRow(episide: episode)
);
```

I understand that the intentions for built-in lazy loading is good on flutter, however I really need each widget to be loaded on the screen because each widget must download a file and store it for use when the device is without internet connection.

Comment: `ListView` ctor does not offer any lazy loding, most likely you mean `ListView.builder` which lazily builds its children on demand when you scroll the list up and down

Comment: I am pretty sure that you understand what I mean, @pskink. I dismiss you theoretical explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply download all necessary files when the screen is loaded inside of the initState method, so that you do not need to care about lazy loading destroying the user experience in case the internet connection breaks down.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to use a `SingleChildScrollView` with a `Column` widget:

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: episodes.map((Episode episode) {
     return EpisodeRow(episide: episode);
    }).toList(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will try this tomorrow and I will let you know